# Attracting users from smaller individual forums here?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of smaller sub-forums about Video production, VFX etc. like VideoCopilot.net forum, The Foundry's forum, Houdini's forum etc. These forums have some pretty good and useful content, and some pretty awesome users.

But the forums themselves are not good enough. The Stackexchange model of questions and answers can greatly help the content over there.

I am not a regular user of this site. This is because I am not really a professional Video artist, just a hobbyist. But I see great potential on this site if users from those smaller "forums" join the site and contribute centrally to the system in their respective tags. How can we make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that many people will want to come here from the forums, and i don't know if we really want many of them here.

Forums live in a different way than question/answer sites. For example, the way things are setup here it is much more difficult to "express yourself" on unrelated subjects. If you go on ranting about things irrelevant to the question, often it will be either downvoted or edited out.

Many forums have "I like this post" feature, but then the author always gets notified exactly who liked it. In a way it's not the number that matters there, but the identify of upvoter. This is not the case here.

But i don't want to be all negative, and i'd say that it would be much better to concentrate our efforts on bringing great number of people who accidentally post on the main stackoverflow. Those questions are out of scope of that probject, often receive no answers, and very often get downvoted to oblivion.

Here are just some examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031557/rotate-mp4-videos-without-re-encoding/26827310#26827310
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349009/ffmpeg-avconv-and-sameq/29862017#29862017
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821158/fps-filter-not-in-avconv/29795123#29795123
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287128/avconv-concat-mp4-without-quality-loss-and-huge-file-size/29794675#29794675
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188385/avconv-convert-sequence-of-randomly-named-images-to-video/29794567#29794567
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658106/convert-numerically-ordered-bitmap-files-to-video-file-using-avconv/29794412#29794412
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711828/libav-rotate-video-then-add-overlay/29793553#29793553

And then of course we have Ask Ubuntu:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/561255/output-pal8-rawvideo-with-avconv/561342#561342
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/458442/merge-multiple-jpegs-into-one-video/548017#548017
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/370160/how-to-cut-audio-file-with-avconv/547995#547995
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/370692/how-to-change-the-framerate-of-a-video-without-reencoding/547991#547991
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/370786/how-to-convert-avi-xvid-to-mkv-or-mp4-h264/547976#547976

Those people would probably feel much more comfortable here. Recently i have began commenting on many video questions i find elsewhere informing people of Video.SE. I have seen one individual moving the question over to this portal, and actually getting an answer that has helped, so it's not a completely fruitless endeavor.

---

What is the procedure for moving questions between different SE?

Comment: Asking a question in an answer is not really the best way... Check this posts to see what's been discussed previously: http://meta.video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration